# C# Pass generic List to WinForm constructor

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

I have two forms: Form_Main and Form_Child and I have to instantiate Form_Child within Form_Main.
Form main has a List and the constructor of Form_Child has a generic List.
When I try to instantiate the child form, I get the following error message: Error  1   The non-generic type 'GenericParameterToFormConstructor.Form_Child' cannot be used with type arguments.
The code of form_Main is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GenericParameterToFormConstructor
{
    public partial class Form_Main : Form
    {
        public Form_Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            Form_Child child = new Form_Child<int>(_list);
        }

        private List<int> _list;
    }
}
```

The code of Form_Child is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GenericParameterToFormConstructor
{
    public partial class Form_Child<T> : Form
    {
        public Form_Child(List<T> list)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to specify the type argument before the variable name as well.

Comment: Don't defile the Form's type/constructor. You can use a public method in `Form_Child` that can accept `<T>` (e.g., `public void MyPublicMethod<T>(IList<T> myList)`). If your list is just of type `int`, you don't need a generic type.

Comment: @ Ron Beyer Thank you, but it is not clear to me from your comment. Do you mind posting a short code example?

Comment: Call that method after you have a created the new insteance of `Form_Child`: `var child = new Form_Child(); child.MyPublicMethod(new List<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })); child.Show();`

Comment: change it to `var child = new Form_Child<int>(_list);`

Comment: @Jimi Thank you too. I do not always have only integers. I need the generic list in the constructor's parameters.

Comment: @Matt That does not work. I get the same error message as before.

Comment: The type of `T` is not the main concern here. You have to modify `Designer.cs`, too (it's a `partial` class), to accept `<T>` and you also have to specify the type of `T` when you instantiate the class object: `var child = new Form_Child<int>(...)`. I suggest to use a method to pass the list.

Comment: That looks like the code for `Form2`, not `Form_Child`

Answer (score -1):

There might be a Form_Child.designer.cs file too, containing the other bit of this partial class. I am pretty sure that does not have the generic parameter `<T>` in it since it is off the track to have form-derived classes with generic parameters.